# Wrapping Zend 1 into Symfony 2. How to share session?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, zend-framework, wrapper

In my job, we are working on migrating our Zend 1 app to Symfony 2. I tried to figure how to do this harmlessly. I found the following SF2 Bundle : https://github.com/mainlycode/Zf1WrapperBundle. I installed it, followed the configuration instructions, copied my Zend app in /vendor/zend and everything is working pretty fine. When I browse my old login route, SF2 can't understand it and ask the response to Zend, and my login form appears. I can log in, and it works, the authed part of the site displays correctly.

Now I want to start revamp a feature where the user needs to be authed. So I created a new SF2 bundle, called BackendBundle. It tried this in my controller :

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
if( $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') ){
    echo 'AUTHED';
}
```

But I get the following error :

```
The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.
```

I totally understand why. But I really dont know how I can "share" the authentification between Zend and SF2.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess was to share the session (configure both ZF and Sf2 to use a similar SessionHandler), but Sf2 stores session information in a very specific way that ZF would probably not support easily.

But I guess you could try to create an Sf2 RequestListener which would read your ZF session, find an auth token in it, then create an Sf2 auth token to finally inject it to the SecurityContext.

What d'you think about that?